# C# Compare two versions using wildcard

Tags: c#, validation, compare, version, wildcard

let's assume i have two "versions" of something.
One is the actual version  ( eg 1.5.2.1)

The other one is a string that looks like this : 1.* or 1.5.*.

I want to validate if the wildcard is true for the actual version.

For better understanding:

```
Validation(1.5.2.1,1.*) should be true.
Validation(1.5.2.1,1.5.*) should also be true.
Validation(1.5.2.1,1.5.1.*) should be false.
Validation(2.5.0.0,1.*) should be false.
Validation(1.5,2.*) should also return true. // This Case breaks all of my attempts.
Validation for "*" only should always be true.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you explain your rules and show what you've tried?!

Comment: I want to build a license check. In my license file i have included a version string that says my license is valid for version version x, including subversions. The standard version.CompareTo(version2) does not allow wildcards and it just says that version2 is either equal, higher or lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer in response to updated question:

```
public static bool Validation(Version installedVersion, string allowedVersions)
{
    var components = new [] {int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue};
    var split = allowedVersions.Split('.');

    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; ++i)
        if (split[i] != "*")
            components[i] = int.Parse(split[i]);

    return installedVersion <= new Version(components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]);
}
```

Sample test code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Validation(new Version("1.5.2.1"), "1.*"));     // True
Console.WriteLine(Validation(new Version("1.5.2.1"), "1.5.*"));   // True
Console.WriteLine(Validation(new Version("1.5.2.1"), "1.5.1.*")); // False
Console.WriteLine(Validation(new Version("2.5.0.0"), "1.*"));     // False
Console.WriteLine(Validation(new Version("1.1.0.0"), "2.*"));     // True
Console.WriteLine(Validation(new Version("2.5.0.0"), "*"));       // True
```

[EDIT: Simplified the code slightly]

Comment: I forgot one the one case that breaks all of my attemps. If baseVersion is actually lower than the versionToCheck it should also return true. Validation(1.1,2.*) should return true.

Comment: So you are now actually changing a key part of the question. Such updates makes your question a chameleon question.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHofman and Matthew . I accepted Matthews answer because of readability, though both work fine. I can't believe i did not think of that simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Split` and `Zip` to combine the two splitted results and walk over the items:

```
string value = "1.5.2.1";
string pattern = "1.5.*";

var parts = value.Split('.').Zip(pattern.Split('.'), (valuePart, patternPart) => new { Value = valuePart, Pattern = patternPart });

bool result = true;

foreach (var part in parts)
{
    if (part.Pattern == "*")
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    }

    int p = Int32.Parse(part.Pattern);
    int v = Int32.Parse(part.Value);

    if (p < v)
    {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
    else if (p > v)
    {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that would fail if there are 'empty' entries when the count of periods doesn't match.